# DAML: Create a template in scenario requiring a ContractId as input and exercise a choice automatically after submit

Tags: daml

I have 2 questions regarding DAML the possibility of automated choices and scenario.
I have this template that requires the input of a `ContractId`:

```
template Create_Creation
  with     
    current_login     : Party
    artist            : Party
    title             : Text
    votingRight       : Set Party
    observers_list_id : ContractId Observers
  where 
    signatory current_login
```

I need to create some of these templates in scenario, but am unable to specify a ContractId (like #0:0), giving me errors such as: `Couldn't match expected type 'ContractId Observers' with actual type 'Text'` Is it possible to specify a ContractId in scenario?

Next, in the above template I have a `choice` defined called `Load_all_creation_observers` that creates a template Creation and loads the observers specified in `template Observers` into it as observers:

```
 choice Load_all_creation_observers : ContractId Creation 
      controller current_login
      do
        observers_list <- fetch observers_list_id
        create Creation with created_by = current_login; artist = artist; title = title;
        votingRight = votingRight; observers_list_id = observers_list_id; observers = observers_list.observers

template Observers
  with 
    superuser : Party
    observers : Set Party
  where 
    signatory superuser
    observer observers
```

As the code stands now, when a user creates a `Create_Creation template` he is required to perform the `Load_all_creation_observers` choice to create the `Creation` template with all the observers loaded into it. Is it possible to perform this choice automatically when a user submits the `Create_Creation` template? or maybe not make it a choice at all and define it as automated functionality like you would do in normal programming languages (if statements). You can only seem to define `do` functions in choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a scenario, the only contracts that exist on the ledger are those that have been created thus far in that scenario. So if there is an `Observers` contractId an `Observers` contract must have been created at some previous point in the scenario.

ContractIds are opaque and definitely not predictable, so it makes no sense to think of a contract-id literal. Instead, when the contract is created, bind the resulting id at that point. Ie.

```
  test = scenario do
    su <- getParty "Super User"
    obsId <- su submit create Observers with ...
    p1 <- getParty "Party 1"
    ccId <- p1 submit create Create_Creation with ...; observers_list_id = obsId
```

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Given that the question about contract ids has already been answered, I’ll focus on your second question.

You cannot execute a choice automatically (you could have some off-ledger automation, e.g. a DAML trigger that does that but you don’t get any atomicity guarantees in that case). The way I would solve this problem is to define a new template with a single choice and then call that choice using `CreateAndExercise` on the ledger API. This is pretty much equivalent to defining a top-level function. For your example this would look something like the following

```
template CreateCreationTemplate
  with
    p : Party
  where
   signatory p
   choice CreateCreation : ContractId Creation
     with
      observers_list_id : ContractId Observers
      artist : Party
      title : Text
      votingRight : Set Party
     do observers_list <- fetch observers_list_id
        create Creation with
          created_by = p
          artist = artist
          title = title
          votingRight = votingRight
          observers_list_id = observers_list_id
          observers = observers_list.observers
```

You could have some of the fields of the choice as fields of a template but as a general guideline, I tend to only have the party as a field of the template when emulating top-level functions.

Depending on your usage, it is also possible to have a single “factory” template with a non-consuming `CreateCreation` choice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! hmm, too bad you can't do that. I feel like that is really missing in DAML. I do like your way of thinking. I'll apply that!